# What is wrong with my array syntax?

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm having a problem with arrays:

```
print_r($_POST['bank']);
```

produces the following output:

```
Array ( ['deposit'] => 30 )
```

However,

```
assert($_POST['bank']['deposit']==30);
```

which immediately follows `print_r`, fails. I feel like an idiot, but could someone help me out? Since nothing is changing the value of `$_POST`, I suppose my syntax is wrong, but I can't see it for the life of me.

Comment: Try using `var_dump($_POST['bank'])` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, I just realized it.

```
assert($_POST['bank']['\'deposit\'']==30);
```

works fine, because "deposit" had had extra single quotes around it.

Comment: or: `assert($_POST['bank']["'deposit'"]==30);`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
assert(intval($_POST['bank']['deposit']) == 30);
```